# Reading a .csv into NSObjects and then sorting them by different criterias

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

This is more a open question than an error-related question, so if you don't like to answer these kinds of questions, please don't flame.

I have a huge (!) list of ships in a .csv file, separated by `,`

The matrix is organised like this:
[image]
repeated with different data about 500 times.

Now, I want this to be read into objects, which can be used further to populate a `UITableView`
Currently, I hard-code data into the object files, like this

```
arrayWithObjectsForTableView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
    cargoShips* ship = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
    ship.name = @"name1";
    ship.size = 1000;
    ship.owner = @"Owner1";

    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:ship];

    ship = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
    ship.name = @"Name 2";
    ship.size = 2000;
    ship.owner = @"Owner2";
```

And so on and on with if-else's. This is a bad method, as 
1) Its boring and takes a long time
2) It takes even more time if I want to update the information. 
So, I figured it would be smarter to read programmatically from the matrix instead of doing it myself. Yeah, captain obvious came for a visit to my brain.

**So, to the question!**
How can I read the .csv file that looks like this: 
[image]
add the ships of, say, owner, to a `NSMutableArray`, in the shape of objects. (So they can be used to feed my `UITableView` with ships.

I would also like to have the option to sort by different stuff, like Country of build, Operator etc. How can I make code that feeds relevant ships read from the .csv into objects? 
I don't know much programming, so in-depth answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, first read a line at a time into an NSString.  Then use `componentsSeparatedByString:@","` to divide the line into an NSArray.  Then access the individual elements of the array by index -- a given index presumably has a given meaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The depth of your processing will determine what sort of data structure is required for this task. This is the method I would use:

**1:** Read the `.csv` file into one giant `NSString` object:

```
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:yourCSVHere];
```

**2:** Get the individual lines:

```
NSArray *allLines = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

**3:** For each line, get the individual components:

```
for (NSString* line in allLines) {
    NSArray *elements = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // Elements now contains all the data from 1 csv line
    // Use data from line (see step 4)
}
```

**4:** This is where it's up to you. My first thought would be to create a class to store all your data. For example:

```
@interface Record : NSObject
//...
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *owner
// ... etc
@end
```

**4a:** Then, back in step 3 create a `Record` object for each line and then put all the Record objects into a separate `NSArray` (something with larger scope!).

**5:** Use your `NSArray` that contains all your `Record` objects as the data source for your `UITableView`.

The implementation of Steps 4 and 5 are up to you. That's probably how I would do it though for a medium sized `.csv` file.

**EDIT:** Here's how to generate the `Records`.

```
//
NSMutableArray *someArrayWithLargerScope = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//

NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:yourCSVHere];
NSArray *allLines = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];

for (NSString* line in allLines) {
    NSArray *elements = [line componentsSeparatedByString@","];
    Record *rec = [[Record alloc] init];
    rec.name = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    rec.owner = [elements objectAtIndex:1];
    // And so on for each value in the line.
    // Note your indexes (0, 1, ...) will be determined by the
    // order of the values in the .csv file.
    // ...
    // You'll need one `Record` property for each value.

    // Store the result somewhere
    [someArrayWithLargerScope addObject:rec];
}
```

Comment: This is great, except; How do I add them to a object (The one you call `record`)The read and separate code was perfect, but this code:http://pastebin.com/Xfru063b does not work, obviously, since I used array pointers. The request is: How do you access the `line`string into an object?

Comment: One more question; How can I make it check for duplicates? I'm adding the say, owners, to a `NSMutableArray`, but as each owner have multiple ships, they get duped in the array. Any good way to fix this? And also, add all the objects with the duplicate owner under the same owner. Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @OscarApeland To do that you could make an (instance) method for `Record` called `-isEqualTo:(Record)` or something similar, to detect duplicates. Or, You MAY be able to create an `NSSet` from your `NSMutableArray` and the `NSSet` will autodelete all duplicates but I'm not sure which method it uses to check if two things are equal. I suspect it is `isEqual:` in which case you will have to override it to  do the check. A final way would be to manually run a for loop over your array checking duplicates. This sounds inefficient but really, that's exactly what's happening under the hood anyway.

Comment: What is the - newlineCharacterSet ? You didn't define it

Comment: @Yossi It's a predefined set by Apple. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html) it contains the characters U+000A–U+000D and U+0085.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the CSV parsing, assuming you can spend the memory it's probably easiest to read in the whole thing to an `NSString`, split that on newlines and then split each line on commas, essentially as PLPiper suggests.

At that point I'd take a detour into key-value coding. Give your columns in the CSV file exactly the same name as the properties on your runtime object. Then you can just write something like:

```
// this method will create an object of the given type then push the values
// from valueRow to the properties named by headingRow. So, ordinarily,
// headingRow will be the first row in your CSV, valueRow will be any other
- (id)populatedObjectOfType:(Class)type withHeadingRow:(NSArray *)headingRow valueRow:(NSArray *)valueRow
{
    // we need the count of fields named in the heading row to 
    // match the count of fields given in this value row
    if([headingRow count] != [valueRow count]) return nil;

    // autorelease if you're not using ARC
    id <NSObject> newInstance = [[type alloc] init];

    // we need to enumerate two things simultaneously, so
    // we can fast enumerate one but not the other. We'll
    // use good old NSEnumerator for the other
    NSEnumerator *valueEnumerator = [valueRow objectEnumerator];
    for(NSString *propertyName in headingRow)
    {
        [newInstance setValue:[valueEnumerator nextObject] forKey:propertyName];
    }

    return newInstance;
}

... elsewhere ....
CargoShip *newShip = [self populateObjectOfType:[CargoShip class] withHeadingRow:[csvFile objectAtIndex:0] valueFor:[csvFile objectAtIndex:1]];
```

The main caveat is that the built-in mechanisms will convert between scalars and objects but not between objects of different types. So if you had all `NSString` and C integer types (`short`, `int`, `NSUInteger`, etc) you'd be fine, but if you had some `NSString`s and, say, some `NSNumber`s then you would end up with strings stored in the number slots. It looks like you're using C integer types (as is quite normal) so you should be fine.

In terms of filtering, you can use `NSPredicate`s. For example, suppose you had an array of `CargoShip`s and wanted every one with a `size` of at least 500:

```
NSArray *bigShips = [allShips filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size > 500"]];
```

Similarly, for sorting you can throw some `NSSortDescriptor`s at the problem. E.g.

```
NSArray *shipsSortedBySize = [allShips sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
     @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this link,
https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser
It is the .csv parser and CHCSVParser can be configured to parse other "character-seperated" file formats, such as "TSV" (tab-seperated) or comma seperated.

Comment: Explain please, what is this? How do you use it?

Comment: u can see this,                     http://caydenliew.com/2011/11/parsing-csv-to-objective-c-with-chcsvparser/                                                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788295/how-to-use-the-chcsvparser-class                                                                                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788295/how-to-use-the-chcsvparser-class