# iOS reading csv file

Tags: ios, csv

I am trying to read from a CSV file in which I use # as delimiter  this is the CSV format

####chapter1 #### The Intellectual Property Appellate Board is  ##A statutory body under the Indian Patent Act ###Above the District Court and below the Supreme Court  ##Immune to a challenge in a High Court  ##Is a Board where the Controller has the right to appear before its legal proceedings ~All the ##None of above

####chapter2 ####Patents Act 1970 has been revised:##5 times###4 times##3 times##2 times

I want to get all the string written in between ####  into one single array. How can in do that?.
I am now getting the whole thing as a string by reading it from NSBundle.
I was not able to find any example. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
NSArray *arr = [strFromReadingFile componentsSeparatedByString:SEPARATOR_STRING];
```

Comment: thanks but am getting output as:  "chapter1 ",
    "The Intellectual Property Appellate Board is  ##A statutory body under the Indian Patent Act ###Above the District Court and below the Supreme Court  ##Immune to a challenge in a High Court  ##Is a Board where the Controller has the right to appear before its legal proceedings ~All the ##None of above\n   \n   \n",
    "chapter2 ",
    "TPatents Act 1970 has been revised:##5 times###4 times##3 times##2 times\n"
)
My requirement is only chapter 1 and chapter 2 to come

Comment: You should use separate delimiter for chapter. In your case "The Intellectual..." string is also surrounded by ####.

Comment: so can u suggest csv format using which i can get all chapters into one nsmutablearray ?

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer you to use Dave's CSV parser, you can find it [here](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)

where as you can find a detailed help on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788295/how-to-use-the-chcsvparser-class)